# Google API Auth without Query Parameters?

Tags: authentication, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-oauth

I've used the [.Net Client Library](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/) for Authentication to the Google APIs for a while now, and the standard method to authenticate (which matches the documentation) seems to be using Query Parameters in the URL.

However, if I fire up the [GAM project](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/) I see that there are no Query Parameters in the URL when I authenticate. How is this being done? From what I can tell in all the documentation, all the OAuth2.0 authentication flows use GET requests, so I'm stumped.

The reason I'm interested in this is I have fringe cases where users need to authenticate a large number of scopes across many APIs, and I hit a limit in the URL which curtails the scopes prematurely. If I can find a way to fix that issue, I can get things working properly for those users.

Comment: Did google impose length limitation on their server?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, i think it has to do more with the [maximum URL length in the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers). I know 2,083 seems pretty long, but when you consider that each scope is essentially it's own URL it adds up quick.

Comment: I see. But say we 1800 chars left after enter api key and stuff. and let's say each scope needs about 15 chars long. To run out of length, we need 100+ scopes!!!. hardcore stuff here :-)

Comment: 15 is a bit low? As an example ```https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group``` is 53, and it's [one of the shorter ones](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing). That brings it down to a much more reasonable 20-30.

Comment: I just checked you are right. We need a full url. For some reason I thought it was only service names separated by space. :-)